# Xpath Expression: Select Elements Using Values Embedded in Tags

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to retrieve the data point "400.000" using the data point ("Vraagprijs") of the preceding "dt" tag. What I have in mind is "select the first dd/span element following the dt element which includes "Vraagprijs" (For reference see the code snippet below).

**Note:** I am not able to select my data point using `//dd[@class=""]` because the class tag is not unique. Also tried indexing but the results are not robust.

```html
<dl class="object-kenmerken-list">
<dt> Vraagprijs</dt>
<dd class="xxx">
    <span class ="xxx"> 400.000</span>
    <span class ="xxx"> irrelevant data</span>
</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This xpath should get the wanted value

```
//dt[.="Vraagprijs"]/following-sibling::dd[1]/span[1]/text()
```

Comment: @LisaHerzog you can mark the answer as accepted if you wish ;-)